# Confusion with virtual pointer of derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Base having a virtual function and Derived also having one virtual function like this,

```
class Base
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        Base(int data = 9):i(data)
        {
            cout << "In Base class constructor" << endl;
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout << "In Base class" << endl;
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        }
        virtual ~Base()
        {
            cout << "In Base class destructor" << endl;
        }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    private:
        int j;
    public:
        Derived(int data = 10):Base(11),j(data)
        {
            cout << "In Derived class constructor" << endl;
        }
        virtual void display()
        {
            cout << "In Derived class" << endl;
            cout << "j = " << j << endl;
        }
        ~Derived()
        {
            cout << "In Derived class destructor" << endl;
        }
};
```

Now in gdb I see the total size of the Derived class object is 16 bytes (int+int+_vptr+_vptr), but when I print each object in gdb I'm getting confused, for base class it's showing like this

`$1 = {_vptr.Base = 0x401010, i = 11}` and it's fine, but for derived it's showing something like this

```
$2 = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x401010, i = 11}, j = 10}
```

I'm not seeing the virtual pointer of the derived class. As per my understanding in addition to the base class virtual pointer which is inherited, there should be one more virtual pointer in the derived class that should point to it's own virtual table. Am I doing something wrong here or is there any other way to get it?

Comment: What's the `type =` thing?

Comment: I just printed from gdb using ptype. Not actual code

Comment: Also why is the destructor taking an `int`?

Comment: Show verbatim code, not whatever this is.

Comment: @Sarath, well, gdb looks *drunk*, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry in gdb it's show like this..

Comment: class Base
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        Base(int data = 9):i(data)
        {
            cout << "In Base class constructor" << endl;
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout << "In Base class" << endl;
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        }
        virtual ~Base()
        {
            cout << "In Base class destructor" << endl;
        }
};

Comment: class Derived: public Base
{
    private:
        int j;
    public:
        Derived(int data = 10):Base(11),j(data)
        {
            cout << "In Derived class constructor" << endl;
        }
        virtual void display()
        {
            cout << "In Derived class" << endl;
            cout << "j = " << j << endl;
        }
        ~Derived()
        {
            cout << "In Derived class destructor" << endl;
        }
};

Comment: @Sarath, don't post code in comments, please. Edit your post and add the extra info there.

Comment: Or, better yet, replace the broken info with this better info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derived class has its own `vtable`. So objects of that type have a single pointer to it. That `vtable` contains entries that point to `Base`s member functions if they aren't overridden. So there is no need for a pointer to `Base`s vtable in objects of type `Derived`.

The reason `_vptr.Base` appears in `Derived` is because you didn't override any functions. The compiler doesn't generate a `vtable` for `Drived` because it will just be a duplicate of `Base`s.

Comment: You are saying if I'm not overriding those then derived class _vptr also points to the base vtable?

Comment: @Sarath, no. The vtable of `Derived` will contain entries that point to the same function as the entries in `Base`s vtable. But the vtables are seperate.

Comment: Sorry if I'm making this worse, is there anyway I can see that pointer in gdb, currently I'm not able to view it when I print the object.

Comment: @Sarath, Like Dietmar said, the actual structure of the vtable and it's function will depend on the ABI. You'd need that to reinterpret the pointer and make sense of it. Rather than learning about this from examining code in the debugger, I recommend you look for a resource that explains how dynamic dispatch is implemented in c++ on a somewhat abstract level.

Comment: @Sarath, I reread your quesiton and understand your confusion. Please see my edit.

Comment: I understood now, will try the ABI and thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

With single inheritance, there is typically just one virtual function pointer: it points to something like an array of function pointers. The number of entries contributed by the base class is known and the derived class just tags its own virtual functions to the end.

Of course, how the virtual function table actually works exactly depends on the respective ABI. You can have have a look, e.g., at the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html) which is used on Linuxes and possibly on other systems.

Comment: Thanks for the ABI link: the one I used to use stopped working a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

The derived class doesn't have a separate, additional pointer to its vtable - rather, the vtable pointer inherited from the base class will be *overwritten* to point to the derived class's vtable as the derived class's constructor runs (and later reverted as the destructor runs).

That way, when operations are done on a `Base*` or `Base&` to the `Base` member embedded in a constructed derived object, the pointer to the VDT seen (at the usual offset into the `Base` object) allows dispatched to the derived class's methods.